# P-channel MOSFET circuit schematic

Tags: mosfet, switching, p-channel

I am using a P-channel MOSFET as a switch on my project, schematic below:

[image]

As soon as I power my board the LED is powered on, indicating the MOSFET is working, but it was supposed to be turned off until I gave a command to activate. My guess is that I've routed something wrong, but I don't know what.

Comment: Yes, first clarify what part you actually used to build your circuit. Was it NMOS or PMOS? Please provide the actual part number. This definitely won't work for various reasons, but how to fix it depends on many details. Please provide part number for LED D24 also.

Comment: I am aware that the schematic drawing is wrong, I've used this P-Channel MOSFET: https://xonstorage.blob.core.windows.net/pdf/lowpower_lpm3401b3f.pdf

The LED is an SMD Green Led 150060VS75000

Comment: If you replace Q7 with an NMOS, the circuit has some chance of working. You need one with a very low Vgs(th) rating. Also, replace R84 with 0 Ohm jumper if possible. You can omit or make much smaller C30. This is something to undertake only if you need the existing boards to work. The best solution will be a re-design.

Comment: What is the nature of the RELE2_OPTO2 signal? Is it a 3.3 V signal or 5 V or?

Comment: You could also use a BJT for Q7. An NPN (3904 for example) should work.

Answer (score 2):

> *I am using a P-Channel Mosfet as a switch on my project*

A p-channel MOSFET won't work in that circuit. You need to use an n-channel MOSFET (as indicated in your schematic). However, even with an n-channel MOSFET you may not achieve your expectations due to it being wired as a source-follower.

> *As soon as I power my board the LED is powered on, indicating the
> MOSFET is working*

No, it's indicating that the p-channel MOSFET you have fitted is conducting current to the LED circuit via it's internal body diode: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.etechnog.com/2019/07/body-diode-connected-mosfet.html). Note that the p-channel MOSFET's diode will conduct from anode (top) to cathode (bottom).

> *My guess is that I've routed something wrong, but I don't know what.*

No, you've fitted the incorrect type of MOSFET. You should also realize that when you do fit the n-channel MOSFET the maximum voltage at the source will be less than about 1 volt and, it will not turn on your LED. In other words you have multiple circuit problems (unless the input is driven hard up to 3.3 volts). Even then there'll barely be enough voltage to drive anything other than a low-power red LED. It definitely won't drive a blue or white LED.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a P channel FET.

You have drawn an N channel FET there.